# read index of array from function

Tags: c, arrays, function

In my `main()` function below, I am trying to use `age_index()` to print a value in an array.

The parameter to `age_index()` is an index of the array.

I want it to print the array value at that index.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void age_index(int age);

int main() {
    int num;        
    printf("pick a number between 0-5? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    age_index(num); //read value from array based off which location
}

void age_index(int age) {    
    int Index[6];
    Index[0] = 23;
    Index[1] = 33;
    Index[2] = 18;
    Index[3] = 121;
    Index[4] = 30;
    Index[5] = 66;

    if (age < 7 && age >= 0) {
        printf("you are [%d] years old!\n", Index[age]);
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, did not choose 0-6");
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: You should choose 0 to **5** not 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems belongs to

```
if (age < 7 && age >= 0)
```

You are allowing indexes of array from `0` up to `6`, while your array index must be between `0` and `5`.

You should use `sizeof` to avoid this kind of problems

```
void age_index(size_t age) {    
    int ages[] = {23, 33, 18, 121, 30, 66};

    if ((age >= 0) && (age < sizeof(ages)/sizeof(ages[0]))) {
        printf("you are [%d] years old!\n", ages[age]);
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, did not choose 0-%zu\n", sizeof(ages)/sizeof(ages[0]));
    }
}
```

In this way, age is always checked on the current size of your array, even if you change it size in future.

Moreover, as you can see in the code, you can init your array simply using:

```
int ages[] = {23, 33, 18, 121, 30, 66};
```

Comment: You mean `sizeof(ages)`, right? ;-)

Comment: @muXXmit2X I edited.

Comment: oh! thank you so much, I am glad to see I was on the right track, but you helped me finally get my program to work!

Answer (score 1):

As the size of your array is "6". The range of your array index should be 0 to 5. You need to change your if condition accordingly.

```
if(age >= 0 && age < 6)
```

Instead of using hard-coded values like this. You can either choose to use `sizeof()` operator in the following way:

```
int numOfElements = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

if(age >= 0 && age < numOfElements)
{
    ....
    ....
}
```

or you can define a macro indicating the size of the array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN  6
.
.
.
int main(void)
{
    ....
    ....
}

if(age >= 0 && age < MAX_LEN)
{
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition from :

```
if (age < 7 && age >= 0)
```

to :

```
if (age < 6 && age >= 0)
```

Your `Index` array has size `6`, therefore its indexes start from `0` and end to `5`. If you input a number `x` larger than `5`, your program will try to access element `Index[x]`, which will be out of the array bounds.

---

Also your problem does not compile. Change the first line to :

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and add semicolons to all the statements where you assign values to `Index`'s elements.